# Two characters to generate a randomized series

Tags: java, random, generator

I'm trying to generate a string consisting of A's and B's only and they must be in random order..
I can figure out how to use the random class in java but I do not know how to make it produce a string using only A and B.
Help?

Answer (score 3):

1. Create a `StringBuilder` object and a `Random`
2. Repeat steps 3-4 as many times as desired:
3. Generate a random `boolean` value using `Random.nextBoolean()`.
4. If the value is `false`, append an `'A'` to the StringBuilder; otherwise append a `'B'`
5. Use `StringBuilder.toString()` to get a `String` object.

If you wanted to generate a string with `n > 2` characters, you could modify step 3 to generate a random integer between 0 (inclusive) and `n` (exclusive) using `Random.nextInt(n)` and then modify step 4 to append the character corresponding to the generated random value.

Comment: `nextInt` can be replaced with `nextBoolean` in this case. Anyway +1 descriptive answer instead of code.

Comment: @Pshemo - Yes. `nextBoolean` is better since there are only two values. Will update the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

One way is: generate 0s & 1s using java.util.Random and then replace 0s with A and 1s with B or vice versa

Comment: +1 for being straightforward and easy to understand

Answer (score 0):

If you need a particular count for the A's and the B's, fill an `ArrayList` with the desired numbers and use `Collections.shuffle()` to randomize the order in which they appear.  If you want a random proportion of A's vs B's (not necessarily 50:50), generate uniform(0,1)'s using the `Random` class's `nextDouble()` method and if the result is <= the desired proportion of A's, emit an A, otherwise emit a B, until the desired total is reached.  Note that if 0.5 is used for the proportion, this is equivalent to generating with `nextBoolean`, but this is more general because you can alter the proportions quite simply.